# What is the idiomatic way to run a Specification over multitple implementations with Spock?

Tags: spock

Let's say I have a `Joiner` interface:

```
interface Joiner {
    String join(List<String> l);
}
```

And two implementations of it:

```
class Java8Joiner implements Joiner {
    @Override String join(List<String> l) { String.join("", l); }
}

class GroovyJoiner implements Joiner {
    @Override String join(List<String> l) { l.join('') }
}
```

What is the best way to check that theses two implementation, or more, pass the same tests?

Basically, I want to run all the tests defined by JoinerSpecification with a Java8Joiner, then a GroovyJoiner, and so on...

```
class JoinerSpecification extends Specification {

    @Subject
    final def joiner = // Joiner instance here

    def "Joining #list -> #expectedString"(List<String> list, String expectedString) {

        expect:
        joiner.join(list) == expectedString

        where:
        list                | expectedString
        []                  | ''
        ['a']               | 'a'
        ['a', 'b']          | 'ab'
    }
}
```

It is perfectly fine to refactor JoinerSpecification if needed.

My primary goals are:

- Maintainable test code (with as little boilerplate as possible)
- Clear error messages (which test of which implementation is failing)
- Easy to run from the IDE

---

Edit 1 (15/06/2015)

Reworded my question & added some details to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Opal's proposal is interesting but is impractical. Not being able to use then blocks is a showstopper.

Lets try a self-answer using another approach. Since the goal is to execute the same specification on several implementations of the same interface, why not try to use good old inheritance ?

```
abstract class AbstractJoinerSpec extends Specification {

    abstract Joiner getSubject()

    @Unroll
    def "Joining #list -> #expectedString"(List<String> list, String expectedString) {
        given:
        def joiner = getSubject()

        expect:
        joiner.join(list) == expectedString

        where:
        list                | expectedString
        []                  | ''
        ['a']               | 'a'
        ['a', 'b']          | 'ab'
    }
}


class Java8JoinerSpec extends AbstractJoinerSpec {
    @Override
    Joiner getSubject() { new Java8Joiner() }
}

class GroovyJoinerSpec extends AbstractJoinerSpec {
    @Override
    Joiner getSubject() { new Java8Joiner() }
}
```

Basically, the only abstract method is `getSubject` and all the inherited test cases are executed by Spock (I have not been able to find this feature in the documentation but it does work).

**Pros**

- It only requires creating a tiny class for each implementation and the specification code remains clean.
- The full power of Spock can be used
- Error messages and reports are clear (you know which test failed for which implementation)

**Cons**

- Running a given test for a given implementation from the IDE is not easy. You have to copy/paste the test case into the non abstract specification or remove the abstract modifiers and implement the `getSubject` method.

I thing the trade-off acceptable since you don't manually run/debug an implementation that often. Keeping the code clean, and having meaningful report worth this inconvenience.

Comment: Haha, I guess it is the prerrogative of the OP to change the question to suit their own answer, but I like your answer. I would have done the same thing if the original question did not imply that you needed to cram everything into the same Spec (looking for an idiomatic way to do it)

Comment: I really apologize if the wording of the question confused you. I have no other requirement that writing good & maintainable test code using Spock. I don't know why I haven't tested the inheritance-based solution before asking the  question. Perhaps I initially thought that not being able to instantly run a given test case from the IDE was a major issue, but it seems to be the best trade-off for now (still hoping for the perfect solution !)

Comment: No problem, it was an interesting problem to look into. I had some fun looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

What would be very useful here is comparison chaining but, as far as I know it's not implemented in groovy, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30796670/groovy-comparison-chaining). Since `Subject` purpose according to the [docs](http://spockframework.github.io/spock/javadoc/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spock/lang/Subject.html) is pure informational I've come up with the following ideas:

```
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0')
@Grab('cglib:cglib-nodep:3.1')

import spock.lang.*

class Test extends Specification {
    def 'attempt 1'() {
        given:    
        def joiners = [new GroovyJoiner(), new Java8Joiner()]

        expect:
        joiners.every { it.join(list) == expectedString }

        where:
        list                | expectedString
        []                  | ''
        ['a']               | 'a'
        ['a', 'b']          | 'ab'    
    }

    def 'attempt 2'() {
        given:    
        def gJoiner = new GroovyJoiner()
        def jJoiner = new Java8Joiner()

        expect:
        [gJoiner.join(list), jJoiner.join(list), expectedString].toSet().size() == 1

        where:
        list                | expectedString
        []                  | ''
        ['a']               | 'a'
        ['a', 'b']          | 'ab'    
    }
}

interface Joiner {
    String join(List<String> l);
}

class Java8Joiner implements Joiner {
    @Override String join(List<String> l) { String.join("", l); }
}

class GroovyJoiner implements Joiner {
    @Override String join(List<String> l) { l.join('') }
}
```

In the *attempt 1* I'm just checking if every element on the list is equal to `expectedString`. It looks nice however on error it's not verbose enough. Any element may fail and there's no trace which one.

The *attempt 2* method makes use of `Set`. Since all the results should be equal there'll be only one element left in the collection. In prints verbose info on test failure.

What also comes to my head is guava's [`ComparisonChain`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.html) but no idea if it would be useful as well as it's another project dependency.

Comment: At first sight, your first solution is appealing. It is nice, concise (even more if you define the subject instance outside of the test method) and does the job. However, after experimenting it on few more examples I realized that it cannot be generalized. It works well for expect blocks, but fails, or starts being ugly,  as soon as you need a  then blocks (thrown, mock etc.).

Comment: Yes, it covers very basic scenario and hides nice debug info. If the question is answered please accept it.

Comment: I think theses two solutions have too many limitations to be useful. I just proposed a solution (I don't know how I could have missed this one) and will accept the best answer allowing to write a clean test suite, with full Spock power, checking that several implementations of an interface pass the same test cases. Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to create a cartesian product of two lists declaratively in Spock. You have to define your own Iterable that will provide the values for your variables.

There is a more readable (using Spock tabular data definition) way to define the data, if you are willing to sacrifice terseness for readability. Let me know if that interests you. Otherwise here is a solution that lets you define everything declaratively, without duplication, but you lose the nice tabular definitions of Spock.

If your implementation is stateless, i.e. it does not keep state, you can get away with using @Shared instances of Joiner:

```
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll


interface Joiner {
    String join(List<String> l);
}

class Java8Joiner implements Joiner {
    @Override
    String join(List<String> l) { String.join("", l);  }
}

class GroovyJoiner implements Joiner {
    @Override
    String join(List<String> l) { l.join('') }
}


class S1Spec extends Specification {
    @Shared
    Joiner java8Joiner = new Java8Joiner()
    @Shared
    Joiner groovyJoiner = new GroovyJoiner()

    List<Map> transpose(Map<List> mapOfLists) {
        def listOfMaps = [].withDefault { [:] }

        mapOfLists.each { k, values ->
            [values].flatten().eachWithIndex { value, index ->
                listOfMaps[index][k] = value
            }
        }
        listOfMaps
    }

    Iterable distribute(List<Joiner> joiners, Map<String, List> data) {
        def varsForEachIteration = transpose(data)

        new Iterable() {
            @Override
            Iterator iterator() {
                [joiners, varsForEachIteration].combinations().iterator()
            }
        }
    }

    @Unroll
    def "Joining with #joiner  #list -> #expectedString"() {
        expect:
        joiner.join(list) == expectedString

        where:
        [joiner, data] << distribute([java8Joiner, groovyJoiner], [
                list          : [[], ['a'], ['a', 'b']],
                expectedString: ['', 'a', 'ab']
        ])

        and:
        list = data.list
        expectedString = data.expectedString
    }

}
```