# Groovy comparison chaining

Tags: groovy, comparison, chain

In python the following statement returns correct results:

```
>>> 1 == 1 == 1
True
>>> 1 == 1 == 0
False
```

Is such construct (or similar) possible in groovy? The following fails:

```
groovy:000> 1 == 1 == 1
===> false
```

since the first comparison is evaluated to `true` and `true` is not equal to `1`. Any workaround on this?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be using AST transformations of course: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/core-metaprogramming.html#developing-ast-xforms

Comment: That depends. If you can annotate (the class for example), then a local transform will work for you. If you cannot it has to be a global one. But in general I strongly suggest using a local transform if possible

Comment: With local AST transformation I always need to annotate class? Can you guide me somehow on writing such an annotation?

Comment: local ast transformations are basically controlled by annotation, thus you need something to annotate in the Java sense. A class, field,method, package or declaration I think is possible.  As for how to do this in detail I think stackoverflow is not the right place. I suggest you ask this on the groovy user list. The link I gave is an entry point, you will have to get a bit familiar with the groovy AST

Answer (score 1):

Or if not the AST route you're stuck with:

```
(1 == 1) && (1 == 1)
```

Which you *could* do programatically with something like:

```
public <T> Boolean allEqual(T... elements) {
    elements.toList().collate(2, 1, false).every { a, b -> a == b }
}

assert allEqual(1, 1, 1)
```